# How do I make an undefined item in an object's length equal to 0 in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to keep track of the scores in each article and display it. However, I run into problems when it's missing an up or down item in the object.

This is my data for all the votes:

```
const votes = {
  "1": {
    "up": [
      "12345",
      "12346"
    ],
    "down": [
      "22456"
    ],
  },
  "2": {
    "up": [
      "12345",
      "12346"
    ],
    "down": [
      "22456",
      "25214",
      "23612"
    ]
  }
}

export default votes;
```

This is how I'm handling it right now, but this requires that there has to be both `"up"` and `"down"` in the object.

```
<div style={vote}>
    {votes[id] ? votes[id].up.length - votes[id].down.length : 0 }
</div>
```

So in a case here you have **only** the `up` element, I want the result to be only the length of up. And the same case for down:

```
"3": {
   "up": [
      "12345",
      "22341"
   ]
} //this would output a score of 2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preferrable solution would probably be to always initialize the objects with a blank `up` and `down` array when you add it to your `votes` array.

If that's not possible, you will have to handle this case during the rendering process, e.g. like this:

```
<div style={vote}>
    {votes[id] ? (votes[id].up || []).length - (votes[id].down || []).length : 0 }
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help !